# Infinite for-loop in perl

Tags: perl

Can someone tell me, why I get an infinite loop? It won't loop infinite with a while loop though.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $i;
my $ipv4 = 0;
my $ipv6 = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i > 0; $i++){
    print "$i\n";
    if($ipv4 eq $ipv6){
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're tampering with the iterator mid-flight, it's a good sign that a `for` loop is the wrong construct to be using.

Answer (score 5):

In a for loop the third statement `$i++` is executed at the end of each block and the second statement `$i > 0` is executed at the beginning.

(You are also using a string comparator `eq` instead of a numeric one `==`.)

In effect what you are doing is the equivalent of:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i > 0){
    print "$i\n";
    if($ipv4 == $ipv6){
        $i = 0;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

You should use a `last` statement instead:

```
$i = 1;
while (1) {
    print "$i\n";
    if($ipv4 == $ipv6) {
        last;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in `for ($i = 1; $i > 0; $i++){` the end condition `$i > 0;` is never reach.

Comment: But $i is set to 0 if $ipv4 is equals $ipv5 so theoretical $i can be zero?!

Comment: @Jens: No, because of the `$i++` that is executed at the end of the loop and before the test `$i > 0`.

Comment: But that is not explained in your answer. please add the information to this.

Comment: @jens I have the reason why if you look at my answer.

Comment: @gh9 Yes you have. But the comment is for M42.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR;** *Because you assign i = 0 in your body, the step part then increments i++ rendering you in an infinite loop. You can add a break statement after i=0 to fix this.*

The INITIALIZE part will be executed once when the execution reaches that point.

Then, immediately after that the TEST part is executed. If this is false, the whole loop is skipped. If the TEST part is true then the BODY is executed followed by the STEP part.

So once you execute the body of the statement, the Step part is executed resulting in I being greater than 1

Reference to the C language spec which the perl style for loop comes from
[c spec from gnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-for-Statement)

The part we care about (cut and pasted out)

The for statement first evaluates the expression initialize. Then it evaluates the expression test. If test is false, then the loop ends and program control resumes after statement. ***Otherwise, if test is true, then statement is executed. Finally, step is evaluated,*** and the next iteration of the loop begins with evaluating test again.

Answer (score 0):

If ipv4 and ipv6 is equals you set `$i` to zero. nextstep in the loop is incrementing `$i` and then it will be comared with `$i>0` what is true. If you change `$i=0` to `$i=-1` it will work.

But it is no good practice to change the running variable of a loop.